# Continuous Aggregation Materialized View, Timescale with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I'm trying to create a continuous aggregation materialized view, the time bucket will be on yearly basis like this (time_bucket(INTERVAL '1 year', s.createdat) AS Createdat).

Everything is working good when I used only one table in the query but when I tried to add join with other table and set where conditions I got a wrong result set, I'm getting fractional milliseconds in date column in the result set like this ('2000-01-01 00:00:00.04', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.045') which is not correct.

The correct date should be in this format ('2000-01-01 00:00:00') only.

I have checked the time bucket function and the query many times, everything is good.

Also I tried to run the query without create view command and got correct result set.

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW view_name
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS

I used the above command to create the view

Note that I have a policy and the view is working perfect without joins and where conditions.

Also note that I don't have a date in 2000's in my table.

I tried to add with data clause , but still got fractional milliseconds.

Comment: Hi Wasfi! Can you share your table creation? Specially what field are you using in the time column and how are you filling it. 

Please add example of table creation and data insertion. Probably something is wrong with the data type not being g compatible with the number being passed.

Comment: First off it is not a `date` data type. In Postgres `date` data types *do not carry time*, your column is a timestamp (or timestamptz).  You can eliminate the milliseconds by casting to `timestamp(0)`. If you query afterward you may actually see `.000` as the fractional part. But you need to keep in mind that that is just how it is displayed, not stored. `Timestamp` data types are stored in an internal representation that does not necessary correspond to how they are displayed.

Comment: jonatasdp I have a table called Steps (UserId bigint, Steps int, Createdat timestamp without time zone) and this is the hyper table.
Also I have a table called CampaignSubscribtion (UserId bigint, CampaignId int, JoiningDate timestamp).
I want to create a continuous aggregation materialized view like the below creation statement

Comment: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW monthlyStepsPerUser
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT s.UserId,
      time_bucket(INTERVAL '1 month', s.createdat) AS Steps_month,
       sum(STEPS) STEPS
FROM PUBLIC.STEPS S
 inner join public.campaignsubscribtion cs on s.UserId = cs.UserId
where
 s.createdat >= cs.joiningDate
 and (S.CreatedAt <= COALESCE(CS.LeavingDate, current_timestamp))
 AND CS.Status = true
group by
 s.UserId, Steps_month;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.